# Java: accessing transient object fields inside class

Tags: java, object, field, transient

Accessing private transient object fields from any method in class must be controlled with some code. What is the best practice?

```
private transient MyClass object = null;
```

internal get method:

```
private MyClass getObject() {
    if (object == null)
        object = new MyClass();
    return object;
}
// use...
getObject().someWhat();
```

or "make sure" method:

```
private void checkObject() {
    if (object == null)
        object = new MyClass();
}
// use...
checkObject();
object.someWhat();
```

or something clever, more safe or more powerful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transient fields are lost at serialization but you need them only after deserialization, so you have to restore them to what you need in the readObject method...

Comment: Thanks, but I want make my fields transient and also late instancing (i.e. with lazy getter). I add it to question.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Most safe (and normal) way would be either directly initializing it:</strike>

```
private transient MyClass object = new MyClass();
```

or using the constructor

```
public ParentClass() {
    this.object = new MyClass();
}
```

Lazy loading in getters (as you did in your example) is only useful if the constructor and/or initialization blocks of `MyClass` is doing fairly expensive stuff, but it is not threadsafe.

The `transient` modifier doesn't make any difference. It only skips the field whenever the object is about to be serialized.

**Edit**: not relevant anymore. As proven by someone else, they indeed don't get reinitialized on deserialization (interesting thought though, it will actually only happen if they are declared `static`). I'd go ahead with the lazy loading approach or by resetting them through their setters directly after deserialization.

Comment: Yes, but transient fields are silently (aside of `readObject()` implementation) set to `null` during deserialization -- this is what I want to solve in my question. I should add it to my original text.

Comment: They aren't set to `null`, they are ust left with their initial value.

Comment: @Tom: in fact they are set to the type default value, thus to null for Object or to 0 for an int for example...

Comment: Exactly as Tom say. Nothing to worry about. Just handle them the normal way. The only difference is that they're never touched during normal (de)serialization.

Comment: @BalusC: I just posted an another answer to show that transient fields are set to the types default value. In fact constructor is not called during deserialization...

Answer (score 0):

Have to post a new answer about transient because it's too long for a comment. Following code prints

```
Before: HELLO   FOO BAR
After:  HELLO   null    null


public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final Foo foo1 = new Foo();
    System.out.println("Before:\t" + foo1.getValue1() + "\t" + foo1.getValue2() + "\t" + foo1.getValue3());
    final File tempFile = File.createTempFile("test", null);
    // to arrange for a file created by this method to be deleted automatically
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();
    final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    final ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(foo1);
    oos.close();
    final FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
    final ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    final Foo foo2 = (Foo) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    System.out.println("After:\t" + foo2.getValue1() + "\t" + foo2.getValue2() + "\t" + foo2.getValue3());

}

static class Foo implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String value1 = "HELLO";
    private transient String value2 = "FOO";
    private transient String value3;

    public Foo() {
        super();
        this.value3 = "BAR";
    }

    public String getValue1() {
        return this.value1;
    }

    public String getValue2() {
        return this.value2;
    }

    public String getValue3() {
        return this.value3;
    }
}
```

}